# Cross-Site Scripting: DOM

Tags: jquery, xss, owasp, cross-site

Fortify shows there is Cross-Site Scripting: DOM for the below code snippet of jquery files:

I am getting in both line of code Cross- site scripting:Dom. How to fix this attack?

```
deleteAccount: function () {

var id = $('#DeleteAccount').val(); //what should i change here to stop Cross- site scripting?

//Few lines of code

var accountName = $.trim($('.display' + id).text());//what should i change here to stop Cross- site scripting?

}
```

Comment: Don't depend on user input to construct selectors for elements.

Comment: Well, you're asking me how to get the value of an element I can't see in an application I don't know based on essentially two lines of code. I'm good, but I'm not that good :). Remediation of XSS can be a labor intensive thing, and I've got a day job myself. I suggest thinking about what piece of data you getting from `$('.display' + id).text()` and whether there's a way of getting that without concatenating in data from an `input`.